# Please change the "pending edit cannot edit" error screen

Tags: feature-request, edits, design, new-users

<kbd>[image: There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.]</kbd>

Eww. Please could there be *some* CSS going on there? By that I mean more than just a margin.

Even better, there could be a Red AJAX (?) popup box, telling me the info rather than an ugly redirection?

Comment: A page with the site's background, not just plain old boring text?

Comment: @UniKitty Anything would be better. Maybe a unicorn?

Comment: userscript coming up soon...

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/TheCodingMonster/41d3ae07e20215dfff19) the userscript as promised.